# Upload file using FTP and C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to upload a file, but I am getting the following unhandled exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

The error occurs when it hits the following line:

```
 using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
```

Below is my calling code:

```
 UploadFileToFtp(@"C:\file.txt", "xyx@abc.com", "foobar");
```

And the method:

```
public static void UploadFileToFtp(string filePath, string username, string password)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.alphabeta.com/" + fileName);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }

    var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Upload done: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
    response.Close();
}
```

I can access the web server using the login info using FileZilla and WSFTP:

FTP/SSL  Automatic Detect

Here is the exception detail:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=System error.
Source=System
StackTrace:
    at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
    at PredictionEngine.Form1.UploadFileToFtp(String filePath, String username, String password) in C:\Projects\PredictionEngine\PredictionEngine\Form1.cs:line 184
    at PredictionEngine.Form1.SendResultsToWeb() in C:\Projects\PredictionEngine\PredictionEngine\Form1.cs:line 157
    at PredictionEngine.Form1.SendFileToWebButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\PredictionEngine\PredictionEngine\Form1.cs:line 150
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Well, what's the exception?

Comment: Including the exception detail would be useful

Comment: Why is this tagged "httpwebrequest" when it's about `FtpWebRequest`?